# Notify user when date is near

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am starting an application (ionic + angular + cloud firestore) and I need to notify users when a date is approaching. * (This date is different for all users and is stored in the cloud firestore) *

Example: The user has an invoice to pay by 6/20/2020 and I want to notify 15 days before the deadline. There may be the possibility of having more than one date for another event.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what have you tried already?

Comment: @SandeepKumar So far, I haven't tested any code yet, my biggest question would be the best way to do what I want. I don't know if I use local notifications or push notifications. All this because I need a connection to the database to have access to the id, date and event. I'm sorry for the delay, but I've been a little busy

Comment: Someone can help me with this problem?

Comment: We can help you fix your code not write it for you. You have to write and then if you face any issues, we'll be here...

Comment: @SandeepKumar thanks for answer. Well, I don't want a ready code, I want to know if it is possible to notify the user using data from the database and what type of notification should I use (local or push)

Comment: sure it is, you can write triggers, schedule jobs... everything is possible...

Comment: I will deepen the research on these methods and put in code. Any questions I will put here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications
You can create a notification delayed.

Answer (score 0):

the logic to solving this problem could be the following:

1 - get today's date.

2 - get the date of (today's date + 15 days).

3 - filter your data by the near date that you got from step 2.

4 - you can run this everyday at a specific time.